# Load data from gridview into a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I want to load data from a row that when selected by means of a button loads them into a format. For this I am doing with the CommandName, as if they were coordinates, clicking on such a row will load this data and so on for all. But I do not know how to do it in rows and cells with textbox.

I did so like it's in the code but I do not know if it's fine.

Where you have two dashed lines is how I wrote it for the Textbox.

In the form (format) I have Textbox and there should automatically appear the data when selecting any row.

```
if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "clic") {

//DETERMINING THE INDEX OF THE SELECTED ROW
    int indexrow = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

     int id = (int)this.gridview.DataKeys[indexrow]["Id"];
   -- TextBox1.Text = gridview.Rows[indexrow].Cells[2].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you accomplish what you want (I think). But in your question I don't see a TextBox present in the GridView.

```
if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "clic")
{
    //cast the container of the sender back to a gridviewrow
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

    //get the row number
    int indexrow = row.RowIndex;

    //get the value of cell 2 in the textbox
    TextBox1.Text = gridview.Rows[indexrow].Cells[2].Text;
}
```

If you mean to use "Edit" mode in the GridView with `EditItemTemplate`, then have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control).

Comment: I do not mean to edit, the Textbox does not have it in the gridview, I only need to load the data of the selected row to another form, in which it has textbox, and inside the Textbox that has the data of what was selected.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: By testing it in your project.